# JQuery Typescript definitions using 'bool' instead of 'Boolean'

Tags: typescript, boolean, definitelytyped

I got the "Definitely Typed" typescript definition file for JQuery and it uses `bool` instead of 'Boolean'.

This is giving me errors in my typescript project:  `Cannot find name 'bool'`

I changed my version to use Boolean and it works, but it has me confused.

**Is Definitely Typed still the place to get typescript definitions?  If so, why is it not breaking for everyone else?**

Is there a better place to get typescript definitions?

Comment: You probably have a *really old file* for a *really old version of the compiler*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct name to use is `boolean`, not `Boolean`.

Definitely Typed is still the correct place to get definitions from.

Where did you get this file? The current version (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts) does not use `bool` anywhere.

Comment: Hmmm.  I went to nuget and installed `jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped`.  I just found `npm install tsd -g`.... Going to try to switch to getting them all from that.

Comment: Weird.  Just checked, and somehow I got version 0.0.1.  (first version from years ago...)  I will update.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems that installing the angular.TypeScript.DefinitelyType package has a reference to the version 0.0.1 jquery typescript definition package.

Comment: It happened to me also. I installed jQuery d.ts from nuget and it has bool references. Replaced entire contents from github

Answer (score 14):

This happened to me as well when I first setup Typescript for an AngularJS project.

1. Go to Manage NuGet Packages for Solution
2. View the Updates section, you should see jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped in the list.
3. Update the package and the compilation errors will go away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is better than the original answer, given that the link doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem - a jquery.d.ts file with `bool` everywhere rather than `boolean`.

In my case, the jquery.d.ts file came from a Pluralsight course.

The fix for me was to stop using that version, and instead install the nuget package.  From the VS Package Manager Console:

```
install-package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

At time of writing, that's version 3.1.2 which correctly uses `boolean`, not `bool`.

(Also, regarding the Pluralsight course, I didn't use their supplied knockout files, but instead, installed knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.)